# convert String to Custom ArrayList

Tags: android

I have a custom Array List need to save in sqlite ,i converted this array list into string using to string method and saved it in database. Now i need again this Array list.So how can i convert custom Array List form this particular String.

Here's the code i used to convert Array to String

```java
ArrayList<Publication> pb = new Array List<Publication>();
pb.add(new Publication("", ""));
String st = pb.tostring();
```

Now I added `st` in SQLite database as a string. My problem is how I revert back to custom ArrayList of publication from this string.

Comment: post an example of ur string

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: How did you saved the Array List? Adding comma (,) after each string?

Comment: Array List<Publication> pb=new Array List<Publication>();
 pb.add(new Publication("",""));
 String st=pb.tostring();

Now i added "st" in  sqlite database as a string.My problem is how i revert back to custom arraylist of publication from this string.

Comment: @Reema Update your question with code

Comment: Check the ans @ReemaSingh

Comment: POst me the string u saved in sqlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Gson` Library to convert string to Custom ArrayList.
Add this gradle dependency in your app build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
```

then use this code

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
TypeToken<ArrayList<Publication>> token = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Publication>>() {
    };
ArrayList<Publication> pb = gson.fromJson(str, token.getType());
```

Comment: I am getting string value from sqlite database like this [common.Publication@8301fc7, common.Publication@11659f4]  and your code is not working here.Here common is my package name and Publication is a class name.

Comment: What are the parameters of Publication class constructor?

Comment: there are multiple fields, like int publication_id; byte[] publication_image; String publication_date; String publication_color

Comment: @ReemaSing Don't convert Custom arraylist to string like using toString method. You should use the Gson library to convert custom arraylist to string like String str = new Gson().toJson(pb); And then put this String str into the database.

Comment: Thanx.finally its done.whatever i want. Thanx a lot.:)

Answer (score 0):

If seperated by ","

```
String[] strValues = str.split(",");//this is the string u saved in sqlite

/*Use asList method of Arrays class to convert Java String array to ArrayList*/
ArrayList<Publication> aList = new ArrayList<Publication>();
for(i=0; i<strValues.count(); i++)
aList.add(new Publication().setField(strValues[i]));
```

Now the custom Class Publication

```
class Publication{
String field;

public void setField(String f) {

field=f;
}

public String getField() {

return field;
}

}
```

or

```
for (String value: strValues) {
   aList.add(new Publication(value));
}
```

---

```
class Publication {
   private final String input;

   public Publication(String input) {
      this.input = input;
   }

   // not needed but implemented for completeness    
   public static Publication parse(String input) {
      return new Publication(input);
   }
}
```

---

---

---

Check this:
You wont be able to insert ArrayList directly into Sqlite. Instead, you could use JSONObject (org.json.JSONObject) to insert the ArrayList. Please check below and give it a shot....

```
//Add values to arraylist item
ArrayList<Publication> item = new ArrayList<Publication>();
item.add  //add the item to array list
```

To insert,

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("uniqueArrays", new JSONArray(items));
String arrayList = json.toString();
Insert the string into db.
```

To Read, Read the string from db as String,

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(stringreadfromsqlite);
  ArrayList<Publication> items = json.optJSONArray("uniqueArrays");
```

Comment: I am using ArrayList<Publication> ,it means custom object.

Comment: Wt are fields in Publication then

Comment: @Rheema are there multiple fields in publication

Comment: yes,there are multiple fields, like int publication_id;
   byte[] publication_image;
   String publication_date;
   String publication_color;

Comment: @ReemaSingh Are u getting wt i'am  trying to describe

Comment: @ReemaSingh Post ur string please Reema...Will be able to code your way them

Comment: yes i am getting whatever u described,u are going right. Now from your code i save String ss=alist.tostring(); in sqlitedatabse as a string.understood.now again i am fetching data from sqlite. I have received a string value which i saved(ss).Now i want back ArrayList<Publication> pb from this string.

Comment: I am getting string value from sqlite database like this [common.Publication@8301fc7, common.Publication@11659f4] .Here common is my package name and Publication is a class name.how can i get ArrayList.

Comment: @ReemaSingh Check the new Solution

Comment: Its Nice.Thank you too much..:)@Athul

Comment: `ArrayList<Publication> items = json.optJSONArray("uniqueArrays");` it doesn't even compile

Comment: @pskink if JSONOBJECT is compiling..it should work...since it is a function of jsonobject

Comment: @ReemaSingh What  is ur situation. Are u getting the solution?

Comment: `JSONArray` and `ArrayList` have nothing in common, they are completely unrelated classes

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>   Updates to Mayur Gangurde's Answer for Kotlin:-
> ```

Import the `gson` using this in your app gradle:-

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
```

Then in your `kotlin` class
Declare custom `arraylist` object variable

```
var publicationListing = ArrayList< Publication>()
```

Then Convert String to custom arraylist like this

```
val gson = Gson();
val token = object : TypeToken<ArrayList< Publication>>() {}
publicationListing = gson.fromJson(str, token.getType())
```